# How to connect to a remote RDBMS on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdbc, rdbms, jdo

I understand that GAE uses its own NoSQL Big Table Datastore for persistence. But I'm wondering if it's possible to connect to an external/remote/non-GAE DB.

I see [JDBC is not supported](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava), at least as of August 2012. But I'm wondering if there's any other way to hit a remote DB and pull in data.

I'm weak on JDO, but I *believe* it supports RDBMS connections. So, one potential avenue might be to find a "JDO driver" for the RDBMS (MySQL) and bundle it up with my WAR. Other than that, I'm out of ideas. Any thoughts?

Comment: read up on https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/

Comment: Thanks @antony.trupe, but CloudSQL allows you to CRUD relational DBs and have them hosted by Google. I'm looking for my GAE app to connect to 1+ existing, non-portable (client) DBs.

Comment: But is exactly what you are searching for (except if you don't want google to host your db). [Java SDK](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/developers-guide). I'm using the Cloud SQL database with the BasicDataSource of the [Apache commons dbcp](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) library and it works like a charm.

Comment: @da_re - nope. You're not reading my question - I'm trying to connect to **existing** databases. I **don't** want Google to host my DB, because the DB already exists and is hosted somewhere else.

Comment: I've understood what you mean :) . But (as you know) you can't use JDBC in the GAE. I think the easiest way is to backup you existing db and move the content to a google cloud sql instance. You can access external ressources with the (Apache commons) HTTPClient, but then you need a external "middleware" ... f. e. GAE <-HTTP-> Servlet <-JDBC-> DBInstance. But I think this is not necessary and toooooo complicated. If you need this connection, maybe the Amazon WS (Elastic Beanstalk) are better for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

GAE doesn't allow outgoing connections IIRC (anyone feel free to correct that), so regardless of JDO's (or better the JDO implementations) capabilities, it won't be reaching outside of GAE.

Comment: Thanks @DataNucleus (+1) - if that's the case (which would be disappointing to say the very least), then what if we looked outside the box. As several other users have already pointed out, there is GoogleSQL; any way to stage data from an external/remote/existing RDBMS in my GoogleSQL instance, and then have my app pull the data down from GoogleSQL?

Comment: Not that this would be the least bit efficient, but if staging through GoogleSQL wasn't an option (i.e. GoogleSQL has the same security restrictions as GAE), how about a process on these external/remote/existing RDBMSes serializing the data and sending it to my GAE app via HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

For any future readers, here's what I've decided. I'm going to host a **secure** (HTTPS) RESTful web service on a non-GAE server, perhaps Amazon EC2 or Beanstalk, perhaps just a simple GoDaddy server. It doesn't really matter because this part of my app doesn't need to be scaleable.

This web service will wait for a RESTful API call from my GAE app. This call will contain the necessary connection info for the RDBMS it needs to connect to. The web service will contains all the necessary JDBC drivers for the capabilities it needs.

Upon receiving the call, it will connect to the appropriate (remote) RDBMS, pull the data it needs (provided by the instructions inside the call), and then use GoogleSQL's web service to insert the data into my GoogleSQL datastore. Once its in there, my GAE app will have free reign on it.